# Proof by LH rule: If $f^{(n)}$ exists at $x_0$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$, is it true that $f^{(k)}(x_0)=0, k=1,2,\cdots,n$?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Question: If $f$ is $n$ time differentiable (i.e. $f^{(n)}$ exists) at $x_0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$, is it true that $f^{(k)}(x_0)=0$ for all $k=1,2,\cdots,n$?

This originates from our class discussion on Taylor's polynomial and exists as a lemma to construct the Taylor's polynomial, which means it will be better if the proof only uses L'Hopital (the $\frac{0}{0}$ case, which is in fact similar to Taylor's Polynomial). In my opinion, if $f^{(k)}(x_0)\ne0$ for some $k$ and let $k_0$ be the first such number, then $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f^{(k_0)}(x)}{(x-x_0)^{n-k_0}}=\infty$, then by L'Hopital's rule and induction we can induce that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^{n}}=\infty$, which leads to a contradiction. Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 0):

notice that your expression is equivalent to (for $n=1$):
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^1}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h^1}=f'(x_0)$$
Now if $f$ is continuous for our desired domain we can say that:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}[f(x)-f(x_0)]=0$$
and the bottom of the limit clearly is too. Now L'Hopitals rule is basically just using taylor series and so we may use it here:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x)}{n(x-x_0)^{n-1}}$$
Now since we know that $LHS=f'(x_0)$ it is a given that the RHS must also, but since on the top we only have $f'(x)$ and the bottom is $(x-x_0)^{n-1}$ it must be that $f'(x_0)\to 0$ faster than the bottom of the fraction, and so it is given that $f'(x_0)=0$ we can continue with the logic to show it to be true for higher derivatives